# How do I find bitboard attack maps non-manually?

Tags: engines, software, bitboard

I am writing a C++ chess engine based on the magic bitboard, where ordering for bitboards is from LSB to MSB in Little-Endian Rank-File mapping. I'd like to have a 6x64 dimension 2D array for all possible attack sets for each piece on every square to save time during program execution.

Is there a resource that has these bitboards already defined so that I don't have to spend several hours constructing them manually, or is there a way to generate the attack sets with a program?

Comment: Of course there's a way to generate them from a program! Have you tried writing the program? It seems pretty easy to calculate e.g. which squares a rook can attack.

Comment: @user253751 I'm having trouble figuring out a closed form formula that gives me a number (that I can use for an attack map bitboard) given a position and piece type. If there's a simple way to do this, I'd love to learn how.

Comment: Why does it need to be closed-form? Write a program to check whether each square can attack each other square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stockfish (https://stockfishchess.org/download/) is open source and uses magic bitboards.
Crafty (https://craftychess.com/) uses bitboards and is heavily commented.
There are other using bitboards, but these two are the best.

Hopefully this helps.